# ¿Cuál es el papel del infinitivo en una frase con pasiva refleja?

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, infinitivo, oraciones-pasivas-reflejas

En una frase como esta:

> Es una nieve que no se ve caer, más bien es una nieve que solo se ve desaparecer.

Supongo que esta construcción es correcta —mi intuición me dice que lo es—.  Pero ¿cuál es el papel, hablando gramaticalmente, del infinitivo aquí, es decir, *caer* y *desaparecer*?  Es decir, ¿por qué se usa el infinitivo aquí?

Si la frase es incorrecta, ¿cómo se escribe correctamente?

Comment: Creo que tiene más que ver con la construcción *ver + inf./ger.* que de la pasiva refleja (que en este caso también igualmente podría ser una construcción impersonal)

Comment: Si, creo que tienes razón.  Pero ¿Qué papel desempeña?  ¿Aquí funciona como nominativo? Si fuera gerundio ("que se no ve cayendo"), ¿ funcionaría más como adjetivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El hecho de que se trate de una pasiva refleja no influye en la explicación. Transcribo aquí lo que dice la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española (NGLE). Hablando precisamente del problema de definir el rol sintáctico del infinitivo en esta clase de construcciones, dice ([26.9e](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pnOcgRAkmEkgdzhP)):

> ... la solución propuesta... [c]onsiste en entender que las oraciones
>   de infinitivo mencionadas contienen SUJETOS EN ACUSATIVO. Esta
>   solución (...) permite suponer que el complemento del verbo de
>   percepción o causativo es una entidad oracional o cuasioracional, como
>   la encerrada entre corchetes en *Vio [**a Rocío** salir de casa]*, con
>   la particularidad de que el segmento **resaltado** es el sujeto de la
>   oración marcada (que carece de verbo en forma finita) y a la vez el
>   complemento directo del verbo principal. Los corchetes encierran el
>   argumento que corresponde al paciente del verbo *ver*, es decir, el
>   segmento que denota la noción vista.

En el siguiente parágrafo (26.9f) se explica con más detalle el tema. Pero básicamente la idea es que si "se ve algo₁ hacer algo₂", ese "algo₁" funciona a la vez como un complemento directo del verbo principal "ver" y como sujeto de "hacer algo₂", y que estas dos funciones no se contradicen entre sí porque pertenecen a distintos dominios sintácticos.

Más adelante ([26.9l](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=peScfwwLdhvaRrI,)) añade:

> Son muchos los verbos de PERCEPCIÓN que admiten grupos verbales de
>   infinitivo en función predicativa. Entre los verbos de percepción
>   visual, *ver* es el más usado (...). Aunque con menor frecuencia,
>   también se emplea en ella *mirar* (...) así como *observar* (...) y
>   también, en el ámbito de la percepción auditiva, *notar* y *sentir*.

La frase, por lo tanto, no es incorrecta. Es posible reformularla cambiando los complementos del verbo "ver" de manera que en vez de aparecer un verbo en infinitivo con un sujeto que tiene que ser apropiado del verbo principal, se use una subordinada con un verbo finito, por ejemplo:

> *Es una nieve que no se ve mientras cae, más bien es una nieve que solo se ve mientras desaparece.*

El significado no es el mismo y la frase es menos expresiva, pero es más fácil de analizar. Los verbos finitos (*cae* y *desaparece*) tienen como sujeto tácito la nieve, sin posibilidad de confusión.

Comment: (Inciso sobre formato) Además de usar un _2_ pequeñito como el que usaste en _algo₂_, también puedes escribir `algo<sub>2</sub>`. Tienes disponibles tanto _sub_ como _sup_.