# verb conjugation for multiple actors in a sentence

Tags: conjugación, infinitivo, subordinadas

I am having trouble finding information about how to conjugate when different people are performing an action.

The sentence is, "I want to see my friends paint."

What I get stuck on is whether the last verb is conjugated.

"Yo quiero ver mis amigos [pintan / pintar]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you actually don't need to conjugate the verb *pintar*. There are two alternatives: one using the infinitive, another using the gerund.

- *Quiero ver a mis amigos **pintar**.*
- *Quiero ver a mis amigos **pintando**.*

The difference is very slight, mostly the same as in English ("I want to see my friends paint" vs. "I want to see my friends painting").

You'd only need to conjugate the verb if you were using a full subordinate phrase, for example:

- *Quiero ver a mis amigos **mientras pintan**.* ("I want to see my friends **while they paint**")
- *Quiero ver a mis amigos **que están pintando**.* ("I want to see my friends **who are painting**.")

In all of the above, note:

1. *Quiero...* is more natural than *Yo quiero...*; you can safely drop the pronoun.
2. You must say *«Ver **a** mis amigos»*, not **«Ver mis amigos»*. This is the so-called "[personal *a*](https://studyspanish.com/grammar/lessons/persa)".

P. S. Useful link (advanced, in Spanish): this answer of mine about [infinitives in subordinates with verbs of perception](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26280/14627).