# ¿Necesitamos el conjuntivo “que” aquí?

Tags: subjuntivo, conjunciones, infinitivo, subordinadas

> Cada vez que sonreía bajaba profundamente la cabeza. **La vi bajarse
>    disimuladamente** las perneras del pantalón, y luego ocultar sus pies
>    descalzos en la hierba.

¿Por qué no hay conjunción “que” antes de “bajarse...”, lo cual es un subordinante, no?

Comment: Si quieres usar **que** debes decir algo como **" _vi que_ se bajaba disimuladamente... "**

Comment: @DGaleano entonces, cuando el verbo (B) de un subordinate está despues del verbo (A) en cláusula principal, no necesita “que” en caso de que (B) es un verbo infinitivo?

Comment: Simplemente mi español es nativo pero no soy lingüista. No sé explicarlo en términos de cláusula y subordinada y esas cosas pero si te puedo decir que el verbo ver se puede usar de esas dos formas. "Yo vi que..." o "La vi a ella...". Pero aquí siempre hay alguien que entiende de esas cosas y te explicarán más adelante. Por eso no lo pongo como respuesta sino como comentario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu duda entiendo que es porque no hay una conjunción si tenemos dos verbos "ver" y "bajar" en

> La vi bajarse

No hay realmente dos oraciones ahí solo porque hay dos verbos. "Bajarse" es una forma en infinitivo con el pronombre reflexivo ser. El infinitivo en español puede tener muchos usos distintos, entre ellos como sujeto, complemento del verbo o modificador de nombre, adjetivo o adverbio. Consulta esta fuente: [Usos del infinitivo](https://slllc.ucalgary.ca/AVal/505/AGUsosInfinitivo.html).

El infinitvo puede actuar como complemento directo. Ejemplos del enlace:

> Prefiero **acostarme** pronto esta noche.
>
> No quiere **salir** sola de noche.

En los que se usa el infinitivo como complemento de objeto directo cuando el sujeto del verbo conjugado y el sujeto del infinitivo es el mismo.

En este caso, consulta la sección del artículo que hace referencia a "Pronombre de complemento indirecto + verbo + infinitivo" y especialmente "**Pronombre de complemento directo + verbos de percepción + infinitivo**" (ejemplos del artículo)

> El médico **le ha prohibido subir y bajar** escaleras. (El médico le ha prohibido que suba y baje escaleras.)
>
> **Le recomendó tomarse** unas vacaciones. (Le recomendó que se tomara unas vacaciones.)

Fíjate que el segundo ejemplo es prácticamente igual al tuyo (Le recomendó tomarse/La vi bajarse) aunque es un caso diferente, porque el ejemplo trata de un verbo que expresa influencia. En casos como

> Hace años **lo oí tocar** en un concierto. (Years ago, I heard him play(ing) in a concert.)
>
> **Los vi salir** al jardín. (I saw them go(ing) out to the garden.)

tienes **Pronombre de complemento directo + verbos de percepción + infinitivo** con la particularidad de que el verbo en infinitivo tiene un **pronombre reflexivo**.

Resumiendo: No hay dos oraciones subordinadas y por lo tanto no necesitas una conjunción. El verbo en infinitivo está realmente ejerciendo como objeto directo en un caso muy especial de entre los muchos usos que tiene el infinitivo en español.

Comment: Gracias. Pero en este caso, los dos subjetos del verbo conjugado y del infinitivo no son lo mismo, no?

Comment: Ooops. Antes no leí bien. :(  Pero ahora sí entiendo. Gracias!!!

Comment: Solo tengo una duda. ¿Si todos verbos pueden tener “usos distintos, entre ellos como sujeto, complemento del verbo o modificador de nombre, adjetivo o adverbio”?

Comment: @Fabiola una distinción: es el **tiempo verbal** (el infinitivo) el que puede funcionar como otras cosas ("sujeto, complemento del verbo o modificador de nombre, adjetivo o adverbio”) en la oración. No es que el verbos puedan tener distintos usos. La respuesta sería: **No**, no todos los tiempos verbales (como el gerundio, participio, etc.) pueden tener esos usos. Esos casos son particulares del infinitivo.

Comment: gracias. Acabo de repasar el sitio que mencionó. Todavía quedo duda de que dice que “En los que se usa el infinitivo como complemento de objeto directo cuando el sujeto del verbo conjugado y el sujeto del infinitivo es el mismo”. Pero en mi caso, ¿los sujetos no son lo mismo?

Comment: @Fabiola "el sujeto del verbo conjugado y el sujeto del infinitivo es el mismo" En el enlace vemos los ejemplos: Quiere viajar por todo el mundo. [Él quiere / él viaja] y Prefiero quedarme en casa. [Yo prefiero / yo me quedo]. En tu caso "(yo) La vi (a ella) bajarse" [Yo vi que ella se bajaba ...]  Los sujetos de ambos verbos son distintos.

Comment: eso es mi duda. Por qué no es lo mismo pero son distintos?

Answer (score 2):

Una oración muy interesante la que planteas. Para mí, tiene un error, pero primero vamos a abordar la subordinada, que es tu duda.

---

### Subordinada

Como ya han mencionado en otras respuestas y comentarios, **el infinitivo puede actuar como sustantivo**. En general, las formas no personales (infinitivo, gerundio, participio) pueden actuar como no-verbos algunas veces.

En el caso del infinitivo, suele aparecer "sustantivado", es decir, funcionando como sustantivo:

```
Me gusta jugar. =  Me gusta [eso].
```

El infinitivo tiene la misma función que un pronombre (Eso), o que un sustantivo.

Así que, tu frase es

```
Vi bajar(se) = vi eso.
```

Como ya han mencionado otros, puedes insertar el "que", pero "que" se utiliza con formas **personales**

> Vi **que** ella se bajaba.
>
> vs.
>
> Vi bajar a ella.

"que" sólo se usa con formas personales. Se debe a que el infinitivo es como un sustantivo, y no necesita nexo.

---

### Laísmo

*Esta parte no es segura, he hecho una pregunta al respecto: [¿Es esto un caso de leísmo?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/27270/17253) *

Ahora voy con el error que he detectado. No estará exento de discusión, estoy seguro.

Para mí, `"La vi bajarse"` es laísmo.

Mi argumento es que
"bajarse", acabamos de decir, actúa como sustantivo, es más, es el **complemento directo**. Como en

> Vi eso.

Eso fuerza que "a ella" sea complemento indirecto, así que debería ser **Le**.

> Le ví bajarse = Se lo vi.

Esto sería así, a no ser que `[ver bajarse]` sea, en sí mismo, un bloque.

Sin embargo, en las perífrasis verbales, no aparece.2ver bajarse" no es una perífrasis verbal, así que no debería ser una entidad única.

La última posibilidad, a la que se agarrará mucha gente, es que sea una locución verbal.

Si interpretamos *ver bajarse* como una locución verbal, entonces es un bloque, y podemos decir `[vi bajarse] a ella`; donde "a ella" volvería a ser CD, y podría sustituirse por "La". Personalmente, me parece muy forzado. Así que esto abre un cierto debate. Se aceptan comentarios.

Comment: Aparentemente no es laísmo sino una construcción llamada de sujeto en acusativo, que se presenta mucho con verbos de percepción. En [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26276/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-papel-del-infinitivo-en-una-frase-con-pasiva-refleja/26280#26280) hay un poco de detalle con links a la NGLE.

Comment: @pablodf76 Vaya, qué interesante. ¿Pero son correctas las dos visiones o solo esa?

Comment: Yo la veo razonable. El problema es que partimos de bases distintas porque para mí lo normal es decir «La vi bajarse», y nunca me planteé siquiera que fuese laísmo, pero quizá tu dialecto sea **le**ísta y eso te ponga más en alerta ante construcciones que usen el pronombre de objeto directo en ciertos lugares.

Comment: @FGSUZ Desde el punto de vista idiomático sí; desde el punto de vista gramatical, no considero que *la vi bajarse* sea laísmo. Al remover *se* de la expresión, dirías *la vi bajar*, entonces uno podría interpretar: *la vi bajar* = *¿qué cosa la viste bajar?*. Esto último considerando la transitividad de *ver*.

Comment: No sé si mi dialecto es leísta, pero sé que es no laísta (al menos de momento, que se extiende como la peste jaja). Bueno, como imaginaba hay puntos de vista distintos. ¿Creéis que convendría discutirlo en otra pregunta? ¿o lo podemos zanjar aquí?

Comment: No soy experta, pero estoy de acuerdo contigo. Una duda: “vi bajarse a ella”, sobre eso no puedo comprender.

Comment: 100% de acuerdo con @pablodf76 En Colombia nunca oirás a nadie (normal) decir "**le** vi bajarse...". Igual +1

Comment: @FGSUZ Quizá convenga hacer otra pregunta. Por lo pronto creo que le estamos complicando las cosas a Fabiola.

Comment: Allá voy entonces.

Answer (score 1):

Encontré el texto original [aquí](https://knigogid.ru/books/260262-vivir/toread).  Creo que la primera frase que citas no es la mejor para introducir el personaje, y propongo esta:

> Conocí a una joven preciosa, de las que enamoran.... La vi bajarse disimuladamente las perneras del pantalón, y luego ocultar sus pies descalzos en la hierba.

Consideremos tu idea de meter la conjunción "que":

> La vi que bajarse disimuladamente las perneras del pantalón.

Esto no funciona.  Habría que conjugar *bajarse*, así:

> La vi que se bajó disimuladamente las perneras del pantalón.

La razón: porque la conjunción "que" se usa para unir dos cláusulas, y una cláusula tiene que tener un verbo conjugado.  Los dos módulos conectados por "que" tienen que valer como oraciones.  Primera cláusula: *La vi.*  Segunda: *[Ella] bajó las perneras del pantalón.*  Aquí no tenemos dos cláusulas -- "bajarse" es infinitivo.

Te doy otros ejemplos de la construcción original, con equivalente en inglés, por si eso ayuda:

> Lo vi correr hacia los muchachos. | *I saw him run toward the boys.*
>
> Te vi quitarte la chaqueta y dejarla junto a la portería. | *I saw you take off your jacket and leave it next to the goal.*

Comment: Gracias! ¿Quieres decir que “bajarse disimuladamente las perneras...” no es una clausa subordinada ya que el verbo es un infinitivo? Ya que con conjuntivo “que” debe ser con verbos conjugados para ambos clausuras. Si “bajarse” está conjugado, ¿la oración puede con “que” y eso se convierte en una clausa subordinada? Si es infinitivo, ¿eso ser una clausa substantiva? Ambas ser correctas y significan la misma?

Comment: @Fabiola - Correcto, "bajarse etc." no es una cláusula subordinada.  No es una cláusula.  Razón: "bajarse" es infinitivo.  ("Clausura" is otra cosa y "clausa" no es nada.)  Sí, también correcto, si "bajarse" estuviera conjugado, entonces tendrías dos cláusulas.  Si es infinitivo, olvídate de las cláusulas.  "La vi que se bajó las perneras" se oye raro porque no queda muy claro a qué se refiere el "que".