# ¿Es esto un caso de leísmo?

Tags: verbo-pronominal, laísmo-leísmo-loísmo

Hago esta pregunta a raíz de lo ocurrido en esta pregunta:

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27253/17253

En la cual, una compañera usuaria pregunta por la frase

> La vi bajarse disimuladamente las perneras del pantalón

Esto es un caso de laísmo indiscutible. Sin embargo, surge la duda en una oración similar:

> La vi bajarse (disimuladamente) a ella.

(Bajarse del tren, o de donde sea).

Para mí, "La vi bajarse" es laísmo.

Mi argumento es que "bajarse", acabamos de decir, actúa como sustantivo, es más, es el complemento directo. Como en `vi eso`.

Ello forzaría a que `a ella` sea complemento indirecto, así que debería ser Le.

> Le ví bajarse = Se lo vi.

Esto sería así, a no ser que [ver bajarse] fuera, en sí mismo, un bloque.

Sin embargo, en las perífrasis verbales, no aparece. "ver bajarse" no es una perífrasis verbal, así que no debería ser una entidad única. La última posibilidad, a la que se agarrará mucha gente, es que sea una locución verbal. Si interpretamos ver bajarse como una locución verbal, entonces es un bloque, y podemos decir `[vi bajarse] a ella`; donde `"a ella"` volvería a ser CD, y podría sustituirse por "La". Personalmente, me parece muy forzado.

Sin embargo, @pablodf76  adjunta esta excelente respuesta donde dice que este tipo de verbos forman una excepción. [(Respuesta).](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26276/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-papel-del-infinitivo-en-una-frase-con-pasiva-refleja/26280#26280)

---

**La pregunta**

Así que la pregunta es: aunque se pueda decir "La vi bajarse", ¿es la única posibilidad, o también se puede decir le vi bajarse?

PD: Es curioso cómo suenan bien "La vi bajar" y "la vi bajando", pero "bajarse", con el **se** parece incluir ya un complemento directo que no está presente en las otras dos.

Answer (score 1):

Como comenté en la otra respuesta, quizá estemos ante diferencias dialectales. El rioplatense no es laísta, en el sentido de que las siguientes oraciones serían percibidas como incorrectas:

- *Él abusaba de ella y la pegaba.*
- *Dala un beso a tu abuela.*
- *La duele la cabeza.*

Sin embargo, *«La vi bajarse las perneras del pantalón»*, que OP considera "un caso de laísmo indiscutible", para mí es totalmente aceptable, al igual que en masculino, *«Lo vi bajarse (a él) las perneras del pantalón»*, y de hecho si alguien dijera cerca mío *«Le vi bajarse…»* yo pensaría inmediatamente que se trata de un español (porque el leísmo es un rasgo que asociamos al español de España). Y lo mismo vale si sacamos del medio las susodichas perneras, haciendo de la oración una intransitiva.

Sin embargo me doy cuenta de que hay un "problema" con ese pronombre, y por eso refiero de nuevo a lo que encontré la vez anterior, que es el asunto del llamado **sujeto en acusativo**, que aparece en esta clase de construcciones con infinitivo ([NGLE 26.9e](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pnOcgRAkmEkgdzhP)):

> ... la solución propuesta... [c]onsiste en entender que las oraciones
>   de infinitivo mencionadas contienen SUJETOS EN ACUSATIVO. Esta
>   solución (...) permite suponer que el complemento del verbo de
>   percepción o causativo es una entidad oracional o cuasioracional, como
>   la encerrada entre corchetes en *Vio [**a Rocío** salir de casa]*, con
>   la particularidad de que el segmento **resaltado** es el sujeto de la
>   oración marcada (que carece de verbo en forma finita) y a la vez el
>   complemento directo del verbo principal. Los corchetes encierran el
>   argumento que corresponde al paciente del verbo *ver*, es decir, el
>   segmento que denota la noción vista.

Más allá de la explicación, sería interesante probar mi idea de que se trata de un tema de dialectos.

Como chequeo acabo de preguntarle a mi esposa qué piensa de estas frases. Las versiones con *la* y *lo* le parecen, como a mí, naturales; de las versiones con *le* solo dijo que "así no se puede saber de qué género es la persona", y cuando ante eso probé diciendo *«Le vi bajarse **a ella** del tren»*, instantáneamente replicó: "Eso es raro, suena a español." Sólo una anécdota, naturalmente (y mi esposa es nacida y criada en la misma ciudad que yo).

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por responder! parecía que no estaba teniendo mucho éxito la pregunta. Por otra parte, qué revés, yo pensaba que la priemra frase "no tenía discusión", pero se ve que sí la tiene, jaja. Yo desde luego diría "Le vi bajárselas (las perneras)". Cosa distinta sería "La vi bajándoselas", que entonces no es CD sino circunstancial de modo. En cualquier caso, ¿hay alguna manera, digamos, "rigurosa", de determinar si es leísmo o no?